# How to write a correct 'bool' function?

Tags: c++, search, char

I have a problem with my code. I wrote a bool function above `int main()`:

```
bool currency_(const char c)
{
    while (c==' ')
    {
        if (c==('p', 't', 'e', 'd'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the program to work, but instead while compiling it shows "control reaches end of non-valid function".

Comment: what does your `while` in this case ?

Comment: "if (c==('p', 't', 'e', 'd'))" never ever in C++, this is not python...

Comment: `c == 'p' || c == 't' || ...` Any [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), class or tutorial should have taught you that.

Comment: Your attempted implementation does not say what you are trying to achieve, so you will probably have to explain a bit.

Comment: If `c` is `' '` your function doesn't return anything. Also why the while loop if you return in any case. Also what  others have mentioned about the weird if clause.

Comment: That is the same as `if (c == ' ') return c == 'd';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function makes no sense.

If `c` is a space character, your `if` statement (had you written it correctly, which you didn't) will always evaluate as false.

And if `c` is not a space character, your function exits with an undefined return value.

And your `while` is useless, since the function never modifies `c`.

You probably meant to write something like this instead:

```c
bool currency_(const char c)
{
    if (c =='p' || c == 't' || c == 'e' || c == 'd')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or simply

```c
bool currency_(const char c)
{
    return (c =='p' || c == 't' || c == 'e' || c == 'd');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
if (c == 'p' || c == 't' || c== 'e' || c == 'd')
```

It's not a good idea to make up code and hope it's correct C++. It rarely works.

But even with this correction your other problem about control reaching the end of a non-void function remains. What do you expect your code to return if `c` does not equal `' '`?

And then you have another problem which is that if `c` equals `' '` then it cannot equal `'p'`, `'t'`, `'e'` or `'d'`. So your code has some logic problems as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
while (c==' ')
    {
        if (c==('p', 't', 'e', 'd'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If `c != ' '`, you never enter the body of your while loop, and reach end of non-void function, without returning anything, invoking undefined behavior.

Also, `if (c==('p', 't', 'e', 'd'))` doesn't do what you think it does.
You should either chain `||` operator, like so

```
if(c == 'p' || c == 't' || c == 'e' || c == 'd'){...}
```

Or, you could use `std::array` and `std::find`.

```
constexpr std::array<char,4> characters{'p', 't', 'e', 'd'};
if(std::find(characters.cbegin(), characters.cend(), c) != characters.cend()) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

put those chars in a vector and try to find c in it:

```
std::vector<char> options{'p', 't', 'e', 'd'};
bool currency_(const char c)
{

    if (std::find(options.begin(), options.end(), c) != options.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

or even better just return the result of `std::find` directly:

```
bool currency_(const char c)
{
    return (std::find(options.begin(), options.end(), c) != options.end())
}
```